# Update Model from Database not updating changed data type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework 4 with ASP.NET MVC 3.

I have a table, where one of the field called "ABC" was earlier of datatype `varchar(100)` I have now changed this to `nvarchar(256)`.

Now to update this in Entity Framework, I have done the following steps.

- Open .edmx
- Right click and selected "Update Model from Database"
- Refresh tab
- Selected the table I wanted to refresh
- Ok

However after doing these steps still in the Property window the "Max Length" shows as 100.

Can some one pls help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this problem several times.

You can try deleting the `ABC` property in the `edmx` and follow the steps you mentioned. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It does not update maxlength of string properties, because the store is not updated.

You can either manually change it in your store, then press update in EF designer. Or you can delete the table, then re-add it and everything will be up to date.(drawback of this approach is that you will lose any custom made changes)

Comment: What do you mean by 'store'?

Comment: @AskYous When you open edmx Model browser, you will see Diagrams, DatabaseModel and Store. Store is the metadata about your db.

Answer (score 0):

4 Years later and this problem persists. I find the easiest thing to do is to delete the .edmx file and regenerate it again for the cleanest and most dependable update.

Comment: you can just delete the table or the field and do the refresh/add.